# Is it possible to clone the operating system to a different machine?

Tags: macos, migration, copy-paste

I have spent a lot of time setting up a speech recognition profile which would be a pain to do all over again. I have configured this on a Mac mini. Suppose I now wish to buy a MacBook Air. Would it be possible to transfer my entire current setup including software and settings across to a different hardware platform?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that Migration Assistant would not take care of it for you? I am not too familiar with the requirements of speech recognition, but unless special hardware is involved, I am not sure I see where problems might lurk.

Comment: All-in-all recreating your environment isn't an issue. However, speech recognition profiles are generally tied to specific microphones, so you may find some retraining is necessary after a migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to clone the OS between machines. [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) are the recommended ways to do so. Make sure both machines are on the same OS version (i.e. 10.7.3) before you do so.

**However**: [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413) is really good. Try using it first. If that fails, then use [SD!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [CCC](http://www.bombich.com/).